# Delete action not working

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to learn ember.js by following [Getting Started with Ember.js Using Ember CLI](http://www.thetechcofounder.com/getting-started-with-ember-js-using-ember-cli/). The tutorial shows you how to build a todo list but I'm having trouble getting the delete action to work. Since I'm new to ember, I'm not 100% sure what code you guys will need to see but the delete button is in `app/templates/components/todo-item.hbs`:

```
{{#if editing}}
    {{input class="edit" value=todo.title action="submitTodo"}}
{{else}}
    {{input type="checkbox" checked=todo.complete class="toggle"}}
    <label class="{{if todo.complete 'completed'}}" {{action "editTodo" on="doubleClick"}}>{{todo.title}}</label>
    <button class="destroy" {{action "deleteTodo"}}></button>
{{/if}}
```

I have a delete action in `app/components/todo-item.js` like so:

```
  actions: {
    editTodo() {**code**},
    submitTodo() {**code**},
    deleteTodo() {
      let todo = this.get('todo');
      this.sendAction('deleteTodo', todo);
    }
  }
```

And in `app/routes/todos.js` I have:

```
actions: {
    createTodo(newTitle) {**code**},
    updateTodo(todo) {
        todo.save();
    },
    deleteTodo(todo) {
        todo.destroyRecord();
    }
}
```

When I click on the delete button nothing happens and the following shows up in Ember Inspector console:

> `Successful request: DELETE /todos/2`
>
> `Object` (with a lot of stuff nested under it)
>
> `Error: Assertion Failed: normalizeResponse must return a valid JSON
>   API document:     * One or more of the following keys must be present:
>   "data", "errors", "meta".`

I'm not really sure what that error means so if anyone could explain and offer a possible solution I'd really appreciate it.

[github repo](https://github.com/sheekap/ember-todo)

Comment: What does the server actually respond with when it sends off the Delete request? The server response your app is expecting should have a `data` property inside it for it to be a valid JSON API response. That's where the error is coming from — it isn't a problem with your Ember code itself.

Comment: How to I find that out? The terminal window I run `ember serve` from doesn't respond when I hit the delete button.

Comment: Assuming you're using Chrome, right-click and open the `inspect element` menu. That'll open a new pane that shows you various developer tools. There's a network tab that displays all network activity. Leave that open, click one of your delete buttons, and see what it does. Click on the network request in that tab, and it'll display details. Pay attention to the `Preview` and `Response` tabs to see what comes back from the server.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting any response from the delete button. I've checked other actions and they're working fine. Not sure how serious this is but I've also put up a link to the github repository just in case that makes things easier to debug.

Comment: It looks like the issue is that you're using Ember 2, whose default adapters (their way of interfacing with the back end) conform to the JSON API spec, but the ember-cli-mirage back end faker you're using doesn't quite work with it yet, as per http://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/docs/v0.1.x/working-with-json-api/ — so your best bets would be to either make sense of the Mirage guides there, or tell Ember to inherit from the old RESTAdapter and Serializer in your app. I've left this as a comment, because it'd make a half-arsed answer, but hopefully it can get you started?

Comment: It's definitely a start, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this: `this.del('/todos/:id')` to

```
this.del('/todos/:id', function(db, request) {
        var id = request.params.id;
        return {
            data: {
                type: 'todos',
                id: id,
                attributs: db.todos.find(id)
            }
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that the response from the server when sending the delete request is not as expected. Ember is expecting your back end to conform to the JSON API spec which is outlined [here](http://jsonapi.org/). This means it is expecting a response that has a JSON object with either "data", "error" or "meta" at base level. In this case, to keep Ember happy, I'd suggest you'd want to be returning an object that looks like this:

```
 {data: {}}
```

This is effectively just confirming to Ember that the object is deleted.